# Why does a loop in R starts at 0 as opposed to the first number in the sequence?

Tags: r, loops

The output of the following loop starts at zero, and has a length of 76, while my intention was for the loop to produce 27 values. What am I doing wrong?

```
 p=0
 for(i in 50:76){   
 p[i]= choose(76,i)*.5^76 } 
 p

 [1] 0.000000e+00           NA           NA           NA
 [5]           NA           NA           NA           NA
 [9]           NA           NA           NA           NA
[13]           NA           NA           NA           NA
[17]           NA           NA           NA           NA
[21]           NA           NA           NA           NA
[25]           NA           NA           NA           NA
[29]           NA           NA           NA           NA
[33]           NA           NA           NA           NA
[37]           NA           NA           NA           NA
[41]           NA           NA           NA           NA
[45]           NA           NA           NA           NA
[49]           NA 2.034472e-03 1.037182e-03 4.986451e-04
[53] 2.258016e-04 9.617474e-05 3.846990e-05 1.442621e-05
[57] 5.061829e-06 1.658185e-06 5.058870e-07 1.433347e-07
[61] 3.759597e-08 9.095800e-09 2.021289e-09 4.105743e-10
[65] 7.579834e-11 1.263306e-11 1.885531e-12 2.495555e-13
[69] 2.893398e-14 2.893398e-15 2.445125e-16 1.698003e-17
[73] 9.304128e-19 3.771944e-20 1.005852e-21 1.323489e-23
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general `for` loops are not preferred in R. Instead there is a family of functions, `apply` and its `xapply` descendants that are designed to iterate over objects similar to how other languages use loops but taking advantage of R's built in vectorization. You could use one, `sapply()`, here like this:

```
sapply(50:76, function(i) choose(76,i)*.5^76)
 [1] 2.034472e-03 1.037182e-03 4.986451e-04 2.258016e-04 9.617474e-05 3.846990e-05 1.442621e-05 5.061829e-06 1.658185e-06
[10] 5.058870e-07 1.433347e-07 3.759597e-08 9.095800e-09 2.021289e-09 4.105743e-10 7.579834e-11 1.263306e-11 1.885531e-12
[19] 2.495555e-13 2.893398e-14 2.893398e-15 2.445125e-16 1.698003e-17 9.304128e-19 3.771944e-20 1.005852e-21 1.323489e-23
```

If you really wanted to initalize a holding object beforehand @G5W is correct. You would initialize the object as `p <- c()` or `p <- numeric()` if you you wanted to specify the class at the same time.

If you want to keep your `for` loop intact you can't assign values based on index. By default index will fill all of the values from 1 until your first calculated value, here it is 50, with NA's. You could modify the structure to something this this:

```
p <- numeric()
for(i in 50:76){   
    j <- choose(76,i)*.5^76
    p <- c(p, j)} 
p
 [1] 2.034472e-03 1.037182e-03 4.986451e-04 2.258016e-04 9.617474e-05 3.846990e-05 1.442621e-05 5.061829e-06 1.658185e-06
[10] 5.058870e-07 1.433347e-07 3.759597e-08 9.095800e-09 2.021289e-09 4.105743e-10 7.579834e-11 1.263306e-11 1.885531e-12
[19] 2.495555e-13 2.893398e-14 2.893398e-15 2.445125e-16 1.698003e-17 9.304128e-19 3.771944e-20 1.005852e-21 1.323489e-23
```

Comment: Thanks, Nathan. I am familiar with the `apply` family, although I never remember if its `sapply` or any of the other. However, I resort to loops all the time, and I know I will continue out of habit. So I'd really like to resolve the OP as is. I tried using the vector initiation you suggest at the end of the post, and I get the same result as in the OP.

Comment: Nice... How would I go about starting an empty vector `p` with pre-determined length, something like `p <- rep(0,27)`, and then filling it in? I understand that starting an empty vector without pre-determined dimensions is very inefficient. Here the indexing becomes a headache.

Comment: if you really want efficiency you should use the use the `sapply` but I guess you could do something like @Akbar suggested `p <- numeric(length = 27);
for(i in 50:76){   
    p[i-50]= choose(76,i)*.5^76 };
p`

Comment: There is an indexing problem in your last piece of code. It should be `p <- numeric(length = 27) 
for(i in 50:76){ 
  p[i - 50 + 1]= choose(76,i)*.5^76 
} 
p`

Answer (score 2):

Your loop does not start at 0.  When you write  p=0, it is the same as p[1]=0, so p[1] is defined. Your loop defines P[50] to P[76]. Then you print out the entire list, and see the ones you defined plus NA for those that you did not touch.

When you wrote p=0, did you want p = c()?

Of course,  you can get at the 27 values you want via p[50:76]

Comment: Yes, I wanted to start an empty vector.

Comment: You answer is interesting (+1), but cropping the results doesn't seem too "clean" as solution.

Answer (score 0):

@G5W, that is not the problem. The issue is that the loop generates a singular array of length 76. The i in the for loop is meant for the observation number you want to select. You are trying to force a dynamic array number and it does not work like that. The values you are generating are for the sequence between 50 and 76. You should subset the array after the loop to be p[!is.na(p)] or change the way you write your loop. make your loop from 1:26, but use a placeholder inside the loop that starts at 50 and increases by +1

```
for(i in 1:26){
  j = 50
  code ...
  j = j+1
}
```